# Home button minimizes the app

Tags: ios, iphone, ios4, home-button

I have created a small app using the sdk 4, app works perfectly fine, but when the user hits the home button to exit and when he comes back, the app doesn't go to the home screen, it continues from the state (screen) which the user hit the home button. How can I reset it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this entry to `info.plist`,

'Application does not run in background'

And tick it.

Answer (score 2):

This information is currently under NDA. Please check the Apple documentation, and it will show you how to modify your application when it resumes from multitasking.

Comment: The apple dev forums are a good location to ask this question. https://devforums.apple.com/community/iphone

No NDA restrictions there.

Answer (score 2):

Apple has publicly announced that iOS4 supports multitasking. Now when you hit the home button, the app does not terminate but instead goes into the background. When you hit the app icon again, the app resumes from background instead of launching from scratch.

More detailed information is still under NDA but that should tell you what is happening with your app.